# Unable to convert the "geometry" datatype to exact coordinate values in MS SQL server 2014

Tags: sql-server, geometry, sql-server-2014, sqldatatypes

I have a field called geom with the geometry datatype in MS SQL Server 2014. and the values of that field return as below:

> 0xE61000000100D2040000403CBDB2CB132B41EC73B54534AC334120DBF9FECB132B41388941901BAC334140C807BD44142B41F441CF

I need to convert the above geometry field to get exact coordinates like `MULTIPOLYGON (((88.84 12.27, 88.99 12.56,88.36)`. I am trying with the below query:

```
SELECT geom.STAsText() FROm tablename
```

But I am getting the values of that field as given below:

```
MULTIPOLYGON (((887269.84910000116 1289268.2723000003, 887269.99799999967 1289243.5635000002))
```

Note: These  are sample values not exact values. How can I get the exact coordinate values from geometry datatype in MS SQL Server 2014?

Comment: Your WKB and WKT doesn't appear to parse. Can you please provide a more complete example?

Comment: Please find the below geometry field value (not full part)
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